# while running ionic build android iam getting error You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I'm developing angularjs/ionic mobile application.

While running 'ionic build android' on CLI, I'm getting that error:
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\Users\Username\FirstProject\platfo
rms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

i updated my android SDK Tools to be 24.3.3 but i'm getting the same error.